# How to minimize duplicate rows with an inner join in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am working on a select statement, but am getting multiple rows.  I am wanting to sort by vendor then commitment.

Statement:

```
SELECT distinct
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Vendor,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Job,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Commitment_Type,
     apm_master__distribution.Commitment_Line_Item,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Contract_Signed_Date,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Delivery_Date,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Scheduled_Start_Date,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Scheduled_Completion_Date,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Invoice,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Job,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.DBID,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.JOB,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Category,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Cost_Code,
     APT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION.Accounting_Date,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Amount_Paid,
     jcm_master__commitment.Amount_Invoiced,
     JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Commitment,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Retainage_Held,
     APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Retainage
from APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION
inner join APT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION on
apm_master__distribution.Invoice=APT_CURRENT__TRANSACTION.Invoice
inner join JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT on 
APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Commitment=JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Commitment
inner join JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT_CUSTOM_FIELDS on 
JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENt.Commitment=JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT_CUSTOM_FIELDS.Commitment
where JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT_CUSTOM_FIELDS.PushtoJDE='1'
```

return
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njUEo.png)

Current output

```
| Vendor | Job       | Commitment_Type | Commitment_Line_Item | Contract_Signed_Date | Delivery_Date | Scheduled_Start_Date | Scheduled_Completion_Date | Invoice    | Job       | DBID           | JOB       | Category | Cost_Code | Accounting_Date | Amount_Paid | Amount_Invoiced | Commitment  | Retainage_Held | Retainage |
|--------|-----------|-----------------|----------------------|----------------------|---------------|----------------------|---------------------------|------------|-----------|----------------|-----------|----------|-----------|-----------------|-------------|-----------------|-------------|----------------|-----------|
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
| ACME   | 19-585-33 | Subcontract     | 1                    | 00:00.0              | NULL          | NULL                 | 00:00.0                   | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5        | 9-May     | 00:00.0         | 878055.55   | 924269          | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6        | 11367.6   |
```

Desired output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPXJ8.png)

| Vendor | Job | Commitment_Type | Commitment_Line_Item | Contract_Signed_Date | Delivery_Date | Scheduled_Start_Date | Scheduled_Completion_Date | Invoice | Job | DBID | JOB | Category | Cost_Code | Accounting_Date | Amount_Paid | Amount_Invoiced | Commitment | Retainage_Held | Retainage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACME | 19-585-33 | Subcontract | 1 | 00:00.0 | NULL | NULL | 00:00.0 | 1(1958533) | 19-585-33 | BuildingThings | 19-585-33 | 5 | May-09 | 00:00.0 | 878055.55 | 924269 | 1958533-S15 | 11367.6 | 11367.6 |

Comment: be more specific with your question. what are your inputs and outputs? what are you getting instead?

Comment: If the problem is just ordering, then add at the end of your sentence the following: Order By APM_MASTER__DISTRIBUTION.Vendor, JCM_MASTER__COMMITMENT.Commitment

Comment: @drum...thanks...the out put is in the attachment.

Comment: @MundoPeter appreciate the Order by hint.  It is still giving me some duplicates.  I didn't know if it is caused by the inner join or not?

Comment: Please show the result you want to achieve as well as the result you are getting, preferably as editable tables in your question rather than as links to images. BTW your SQL would be much more readable if you aliased your table names

Comment: @NickW Thanks...I added an image of the desired output.  I will work on the alias table names.  thanks

Comment: Some of the joins might be causing the problem. Try removing the joins one by one, including the fields asociated to the tables removed in order to determine which table/join is introducing the duplicates. Maybe in the ON clasue of some join you must specify more than one field.. It depends on the tables design which we do not know since you did not shared.

Comment: You really need to put both the actual and required output in your question as editable tables - how do you expect anyone to compare the 2 results when they are linked in 2 different images? Also, are all those columns necessary for illustrating the issue or are most of them just noise? Consider creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you rewrite your heading as a question? I help out with SQL questions and tend to pass over statements.

Comment: If you add the PK for each table into your select list it should become apparent which table is returning multiple rows